# "Help System" for desktop application based on .NET 2010 , C# and WPF

Tags: .net, desktop, viewer, help-viewer-1.0

I searched for some time but could not find any answer that give me clear idea. so i am posting my question.
I am working on desktop application on .NET 2010, C# , WPF as front end and SQL 2008 back end. 
I was looking at the options of include context sensitive help. I looked for MS Help Viwer 1.0. It looks promising but what other options do I have to add Help in my application?
There is one more Microsoft HTML help 1.4 available on MSDN.
Which one is best help engine available that works well with .NET based application?
Any suggestions is appreciated.
Thanks,
N Avatar

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question, and also not an easy one to do right.  I've done it myself in the past, and the amount of knowledge you'll need is too much for this forum.  However, I did find a post at another forum with several helpful links.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/devdocs/thread/207a4158-18ac-4227-b430-93d54414c5cc

When I did mine, I used [HtmlHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670169(VS.85).aspx) to create Help (.chm) files, and linked them into the program using the [HelpProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx).

In retrospect, the process was so painful that I instead focused on making applications so intuitive that help was not necessary.  (This is a good design idea if you can pull it off, and is once again getting focus in the development community under the moniker "[Self-Evident Computing](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/hiner/?p=6305)".)

**Edit**

THIS links will probably be the most useful for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ksk25ts.aspx

Comment: @ Thanks David. I went through the links you have provided. It is good but it is based on .CHM old html help technique. I really like the "self -evident computing" article. I enjoyed reading it. I posted this question to get more information and I will back with more info. I will read more on Help Provide, self evident computing. Thanks for your information. This help thing is more complex then i thought.. hehe

Answer (score 0):

Try robohelp. It is not cheap but easy to use and will save you a lot of time.